# LPT ports in C#

Tags: c#, lpt

I'd like to send some instructions while one of pins of LPT port is on.

I was trying to do something like this:

When LPT port 379 (889 dec) is different from dec 120 then stop doing part of code.

```
while ((PortAccess.Output(889,120))
```

I don't know how to do it. I was trying to do something with construction:

```
while ((PortAccess.Equals())
```

but you need to compare 2 objects..

I suppose it must be very simple solution for this problem.. :)

Comment: I didn´t found PortAccess in my Framework 4: What library are you using?

Comment: @nabuchodonossor It's a code snippet wrapping inpout32.dll, found in various places like in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/56ae3e6d-999d-4260-b19c-934775a9206a/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need PortAccess.Input:

```
while (PortAccess.Input(889) == 120)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

This assumes that "PortAccess" is a wrapper around the native inpout32.dll such as described in [this tutorial](http://www.thaiio.com/prog-cgi/CshapeParallelPort.htm).

Comment: PortAccess is not a standard library, please provide more info